# Run Android OS in a virtual machine on PC

Tags: 5.0-lollipop, virtualbox

I was trying to set up a virtual machine of Android 5.0 and it didn't work out that well. I got the ISO and Virtual Box. I created a virtual machine in VB and I selected the ISO and powered on the VM in Virtual Box. It loads and then it reboots. The Android OS just keeps loading and rebooting all the time. Please note I was able to run all the previous Android versions successfully on a VM with no errors.

How can I get Android 5.0 to work in a Virtual Box VM?

Comment: please recheck your steps: http://www.fixedbyvonnie.com/2015/03/how-to-install-android-5-0-lollipop-in-virtualbox-windows/

Comment: Can I download Android Oreo 8.0 from official android website and install it to Hyper - V as a VM???