# Turn a physical device into a virtual machine for use on a PC

Tags: rooting, virtualization

How can I turn a physical device (specifically [this](https://android.stackexchange.com/q/188655)) into a virtual machine for use on a computer?

I am doing this so I can safely attempt to root my device without bricking the physical one

It should be obvious, but the device is not rooted

Comment: "It should be obvious" - how? Phones are using ARM SoCs; PCs have x86/x64 CPUs. Existing Android emulators don't run images ripped from phones, they have dedicated x86/x64 system images compiled explicitly for them.

Comment: @AndyYan Sorry I was not clear. I meant it should be obvious that the device is not rooted, not that the answer to my problem is obvious

Comment: Duplicate: https://android.stackexchange.com/q/133143/218526

Answer (score 0):

Not possible. Rooting is highly hardware-dependent operation and it cannot be done *virtually* outside the device

Comment: So is there no "safe" way to root the phone?

Comment: Nope. Rooting usually is not "safe"